# Unable to Select Record from Database

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I am learning PHP and SQL, and I'm trying to figure out how to select a record from a database.
I created a function called `selectById()`

Right now in the browser displayed is "Error:"  but, no specific error was displayed.

```
 // function selectById --------------------------------------------------------------------
    function selectById($pUInput) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblStudents 
                            WHERE id='$pUInput[0]'");

            if (!mysql_query($sql))
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }
            echo "Record Selected";

    }
```

**PHP Code:**

```
//Call function mainline

mainline();

// Declare the function mainline
function mainline() {

    $uInput = getUserInput();

    $connectDb = openConnect(); // Open Database Connection
    selectDb($connectDb); // Select Database
    doAction($uInput);
    //display();
    //closeConnect();

}

//Declare function getUserInput --------------------------------------------------------
function getUserInput() {

    echo "In the function getUserInput()" . "<br/>";

    // Variables of User Input
    $idnum = $_POST["idnum"];              // id (NOTE: auto increments in database)
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];             // first name
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];            // last name
    $major = $_POST["major"];           // major
    $year = $_POST["year"];            // year
    $action = $_POST["action"];       // action (select, insert, update, delete)

    $userInput = array($idnum, $fname, $lname, $major, $year, $action);

    return $userInput;
}

function doAction($pUserInput) {
    echo "In function doAction()" . "<br/>";

    if ($pUserInput[5] == "sel") {
        selectById($pUserInput);    

    } elseif ($pUserInput[5] == "ins") {
        insert($pUserInput);    
    }

}

// Create a database connection --------------------------------------------------------
function openConnect() {
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root_user", "password");
        echo "Opened Connection!" . "<br/>";

    if(!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    return $connection;
}

// Select a database to ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
function selectDb($pConnectDb) {
    $dbSelect = mysql_select_db("School", $pConnectDb);
    if(!$dbSelect) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
    echo "You are in the School database! <br/>";   
    }

}

// function select ---------------------------------------------------------------------
function selectById($pUInput) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblStudents 
                        WHERE id='$pUInput[0]'");

        if (!mysql_query($sql))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "Record Selected";

}

// function insert -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function insert($pUInput) {

    $sql="INSERT INTO tblStudents (first_name, last_name, major, year)
          VALUES
         ('$pUInput[1]','$pUInput[2]','$pUInput[3]', '$pUInput[4]')";


        if (!mysql_query($sql))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "1 record added";
}



?>
```

**SQL Syntax:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblStudents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `major` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `year` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a query on a query result. This will not work. You will need to use something along the lines of

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblStudents 
                        WHERE id='" . $pUInput[0] . "'");

if (!$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

Which would assign $row an array value if the query did not fail. You may also want to filter the pUinput as well with mysql_real_escape_string  as you do not necessarily know what it contains (or statically cast it to an integer).

**EDIT**

Added a bit extra information.

Comment: thank you for the response. (i'm new to PHP and SQL, i'm trying to fully understand your answer.) So, the statement in the selectById() function will not actually select the record by that one statement alone--it needs the function mysql_fetch_assoc(). i'm just summarizing what i think i understand...

Comment: Keep http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html in mind and take a look at http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string . Or even better use parametrized queries, see e.g. http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements